# Get current system UTC date and time and add 5 seconds to it and format it in the required format in single line

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, utc, spring-el

So I'm working on a project and I need to do this:

The required format : **2021-06-17T09:23:01** (UTC timing)

The main thing is need to do it in Spring boot Expression

```
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("code comes here");
System.out.println(exp.getValue());
```

I have tried so so so many combinations and below are some:

```
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss\").format(new java.util.Date().from( new java.util.Date().toInstant().plusSeconds(5)))");
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("new java.text.DateFormat.getInstance().format(new java.util.Date().from( new java.util.Date().toInstant().plusSeconds(5)))");
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("new java.util.Date().toInstant().plusSeconds(5)");
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss\").format(new java.util.Date().toInstant().plusSeconds(5))");
```

I'm stuck with at least one problem in everything.....So please try to correct it or give correct one plz

Comment: Can you explain _why_ it needs to be done in a Spring Expression ?

Comment: Why are you mixing the legacy `java.util.Date` api and the "new" `java.time` api? Did you try creating a method that contains the code you want to have executed and once that works call that method in an expression?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe It's client request

Comment: @Thomas I can't initialize new java.time.(anything)

Comment: What about `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)`? Can you try that?

Comment: @deHaar I can't initialize it as" new java.time.OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)"

Comment: OK, then use `new Date().toInstant().plusSeconds(5).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))`, might work ;-)

Comment: No.......the ZoneOffset and DateTimeFormatter causes problem.....we have to initialize full package using new keyword.....so can't initialize it as new java.time.ZoneOffsert.UTC....literally every java.time package we can't use

Answer (score 3):

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Demo using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).plusSeconds(5)
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-17T09:45:14
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/uRX0HX)

If you do not want to use the static methods like `ZonedDateTime.now`, `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern` etc. (as you have commented), you can do it as shown below:

```
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Date().toInstant().plusSeconds(5).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(
                new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH)));
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/XQQkpW)

Based on this, you can create your expression as follows:

```
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("new Date().toInstant().plusSeconds(5).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern(\"uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss\").toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH))");
```

For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `Instant` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so using [`Date#from`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-):

```
Date.from(new Date().toInstant().plusSeconds(5))
```

Alternatively,

```
new Date(new Date().toInstant().plusSeconds(5).toEpochMilli())
```

However, you need `SimpleDateFormat` to format an object of `java.util.Date` and the problem with `SimpleDateFormat` is that it uses the JVM's timezone by default. If you need the date-time in a particular timezone, you need to set the timezone to `SimpleDateFormat` explicitly beforehand e.g.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
String formatted = sdf.format(date); // date is an instance of java.util.Date
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: You can't directly initialize anything like Instant, ZoneOffset, DateTimeFormatter

Comment: @ari - Your requirement seems to be very rigid. I think the last snippet of code in my answer should meet your requirement.

Comment: Yes.......the only thing that causes problem is ......we can't direct use ZoneOffset.UTC so we need to initialize the whole package like new java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC but the thing is its not possible inside Expressions...

Comment: yes sir but I need the time in UTC only if u see my question clearly.....